# How to input a 'onchange' event on several checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="111111">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="222222">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="333333">
```

And i'm trying to get the value from the selected checkbox

```
    $("input:checkbox[name^='foo']").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        alert(val);
    });
```

But the event isn't called.. Am I doing something wrong?

Sorry for bad english!

Comment: in which event you are calling?

Comment: generally speaking you should probably be identifying them with a class instead of by name in this situation

Comment: Hmm, the ".each" shoundn't do the work?

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/58bvX/

Comment: you code is fine, you are doing this in which event that's the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `each`.

Use `.on('change')` for your event. Also `this.value` is easier than `$(this).val()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/65u2t/

```
$("input:checkbox[name^='foo']").on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    alert(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

USe `is(":checked")` to check whether the checkbox is checked

```
$("input:checkbox[name^='foo']").click(function () {
    $("input:checkbox[name^='foo']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/151/)

Answer (score 1):

Something very fundamental many of us for get is DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox[name^='foo']").on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value + ' --- ' + this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vZxAL/1/)